# MYSQL dynamic query from rows to columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table

| or_id | emp_id | cs | val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | x | 3.4 |
| 100 | 1 | x | 4.5 |
| 100 | 1 | y | 5 |
| 100 | 1 | y | 6 |
| 200 | 2 | a | 12 |
| 200 | 2 | b | 11 |
| 200 | 2 | c | 14 |

I want my output table like:

| or_id | emp_id | CS1 | CS2 | CS3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | x | y |  |
| 200 | 2 | a | b | c |

I tried every possible code but nothing seems to work. I want dynamic code for this.

This query is working, but for larger dataset the execution time is lengthy, so I need an optimized code.

```
select distinct or_id,emp_id,
(select cs from (
select distinct cost_center from orl where emp_id=m.emp_id) a limit 1 offset 0 ) cs1,
(select cost_center from (
select distinct cost_center from orl  where emp_id=m.emp_id) a limit 1 offset 1 ) cs2,
(select cost_center from (
select distinct cost_center from orl where emp_id=m.emp_id) a limit 1 offset 2 ) cs3
from orl m
```

Comment: Please be clear about what you want to achieve, and what code have you used?

Comment: Mysql or SQL server? They are quite different!

Comment: Confusing and irrelevant tags removed! Add back only the relevant tags please. Tags are designed to gather the correct audience for your question, adding rubbish tags does not help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I return pivot table output in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/how-can-i-return-pivot-table-output-in-mysql)

Comment: Each make and version of database server has its own dialect of SQL. Please [edit] your question to add a [tag](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database you use. [tag:postgresql]? [tag:mysql]? [tag:sql-server]? [tag:oracle]? [tag:google-bigquery]? [tag:amazon-redshift]? Another?

Comment: Is there any specific reason for the ordering of "a, b, c" in the second line instead of "b, c, a" or other ordering?

Comment: no there isn't any specific reason for the ordering it can be random

Comment: Will you always return three CS columns? (SQL is statically and strongly typed, in part that means result sets always have the same columns. Wanting a dynamic number of columns is often a sign of a flawed design / code smell. If that's what you want, please also describe why as there are often more suitable design patterns in SQL).

Comment: Please specify which version of MySQL, as MySQL8 has many features not available in MySQL5.x

Comment: The idea here is that for the same emp_id whenever I get a new unique row that will contain a unique value ( in column CS), that should be converted to a new column [cs1,cs2...] in the resultant table. Let say I got a new value 'PQR' in (column CS) for emp_id =2 then in resultant table I want a new column name CS4 which will contain this value 'PQR'. Currently I m working on Mysql 8.0.

Comment: `If that's what you want, please also describe *why* as there are often more suitable design patterns in SQL.` *(SQL quite deliberately doesn't natively support dynamically varying numbers of columns. Wanting that indicates you're trying to use SQL against its intentional design. This can either indicate that a different pattern would be better suited, or that formatting the data in a different layer / language would be more appropriate. Unless you explain the reasons for your desired behaviour, this appears as an https://xyproblem.info problem.)*

Comment: according to the data I have , yes It will always return three CS_ columns and for that I have used a subquery but it was not efficient as the query was heavy and taking longer time to execute

Comment: Please do not use `distinct` when it is not needed. It is not needed because you also use `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: Use `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cs)` instead of 3 columns for the cs values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For three CS columns, in MYSQL8

```
WITH
  sorted AS
(
  SELECT
    or_id,
    emp_id,
    cs,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY or_id, emp_id ORDER BY cs) AS ordinal
  FROM
    your_table
  GROUP BY
    or_id,
    emp_id,
    cs
)
SELECT
  or_id,
  emp_id,
  MAX(CASE WHEN ordinal = 1 THEN cs END) AS cs1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN ordinal = 2 THEN cs END) AS cs2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN ordinal = 3 THEN cs END) AS cs3
FROM
  sorted
GROUP BY
  or_id,
  emp_id
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/2QNiXt6O